# Xamarin Continuously Breaks with Multiple Different Errors

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Okay so I wanted to get into mobile development and decided to start with Android Studio, but I wanted to more easily reach both Android and IOS so switched over to Xamarin.

Honestly, Xamarin looks really cool and I have been trying so hard to get into it, but every time I open a new Xamarin project it seems to break right away before I really get to do anything.

Sometimes it asks me to update something so I do so before I begin development and it breaks, sometimes I run an initial build right when I make the project with no changes made and it breaks. Sometimes I do something as simple as adding a button or entry in the XAML code and it just breaks, and when I erase **all my changes** it is still broken.

I just want to know, is this just me or is this just how Xamarin is? I know there is a huge chance it is just me having no idea what I'm doing, but the project seems to break even when I follow updated tutorials and documentation. I have gotten errors even involving the file path it made.

**Summary**

The short time I used Android Studio I was able to get decently far into development and it still didn't break, but with Xamarin I am having a hard time just getting past the creation of the project without some error. Why is this? Does this happen to experienced Xamarin Developers or just for beginners?

Comment: I am currently creating an App using code that already is in use with another XF app so I know it works. I also get a variety of build errors that are cause by the build environment and not the code itself. My advice is to definitely work with some versioning tool (like Git or SVN) get to a stable version an commit often. At least you can revert to a state where you can be sure that there are no code changes and build artifacts lingering

Comment: If you are interested in only creating iOS and Android Apps then VS for Mac might be an option. In my experience the builds are faster and less error prone. However VS for Mac has a lot less functionality than the windows version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are certainly issues in Xamarin Mobile Development. Those issues you are referering, happen to everyone from time to time (not that common these days though).

Ignore compiling errors (assuming its the programmer's fault), those issues are usually related with Visual Studio. So, the process is always the same:

- Clean Solution
- Delete bin/objs folders (if the clean has errors)
- Restart Visual Studio
- Rebuild

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm glad there is somewhat of a solution, but it seems like there is a decently long process every time some error occurs to fix it. And I've noticed a lot of general complaints with Xamarin when people say sometimes you have an error that isn't really an error and its all just very confusing. I'm glad I tried Xamarin but it just seems to tedious and problematic for me. I think I will continue using Android Studio for now, but thanks for the assist.

Comment: If you are using a git repository, you can do open that folder in terminal, and pass in "git clean -fxd" and it will do the deleting for you